# Instagram can`t find location created on Facebook or Foursquare

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, foursquare, instagram-api

I have a Facebook and Foursquare place named as 'Aenea Tattoo Studio'
If I

- use its Facebook ID in the Instagram API `/locations/search` as a `facebook_places_id=1594009447547294`
- use its Foursquare ID in the Instagram API `/locations/search` as a `foursquare_v2_id=54fe044a498eb8d13d38b6bf`

  I receive this response:

  {
    "data" : [],
    "meta" : {
      "code" : 200
    }
  }

meaning that I have no location on Instagram linked to this Facebook/Foursquare place.

How can I create an Instagram location so that my Facebook/Foursquare place is connected to the new Instagram location?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the Page is not directly mapped/indexed to Instagram. Although it seems that the place is indexed.

If you get the location from the Facebook Place, and then use that to search in Instagram, using the following call:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=59.9129486&lng=30.2961197&distance=100`

In the results you will see:

```
{
  "latitude": 59.912869271,
  "id": "171453560",
  "longitude": 30.297031403,
  "name": "10-я Красноармейская ул."
},
```

which I believe is the same address as the Facebook Page.

I'm not sure if there is a guarantee that all Facebook Pages/Locations should also be available via the Instagram API; I'll try to find that out for you.

About Foursquare I would not know. Hopefully somebody else can help you with that.

Comment: Flaxfield, thanks! 
I`ve also reported the issue to instagram support about this thing

Comment: I haven't played with the APIs, but did you find out if a Facebook location you create *should* always show up in Instagram or do only a subset (e.g. popular ones)?